# Why can't express router find my build files on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I know this seems like a dumb question, but I've deployed this same app to google and heroku successfully previously, but when I try to deploy to elastic beanstalk using code pipeline it doesn't matter where I direct it to the build files, it always replies with {"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"stat","path":"/var/app/current/build/index.html","expose":false,"statusCode":404,"status":404}

Is there something about AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployment that I don't know about?

Here is the current address for the build, I have tried '/build' and ".." ,"/build" and pretty much every other combination I can think of to direct to the build files... (I have been stuck on this 2 days now...)

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
});
```

In the buildspec file I have asked it to move the build folder to the root directory, because code pipeline does not support moving build file artifacts to folders with a forward slash (i.e. it can't move files into client/build which is where I normally leave the build files).

```
Build file:

    version: 0.2
    
    phases:
      pre_build:
        commands:
          - cd client && npm install && cd ..
          - cd server && npm install && cd ..
      build:
        commands:
          - cd client && npm run build && cd ..
      post_build:
        commands:
          - mv ./client/build ./build
    artifacts:
      secondary-artifacts:
        client:
          files:
            - '**/*'
          base-directory: build
        server:
          files:
            - '**/*'
          base-directory: server
```

And here is the output from the build:

```
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:07 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:07 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:07 Entering phase BUILD
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:07 Running command cd client && npm run build && cd ..

> my-app@0.1.0 build /codebuild/output/src398857100/src/client
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
File sizes after gzip:

  418.64 kB  build/static/js/main.a6efd13b.js
  1.77 kB    build/static/js/787.8dac752f.chunk.js
  541 B      build/static/css/main.073c9b0a.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  npm install -g serve
  serve -s build

Find out more about deployment here:

  https://cra.link/deployment

[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Running command mv ./client/build ./build

[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Preparing to copy secondary artifacts client
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Expanding base directory path: build
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Assembling file list
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Expanding build
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Expanding file paths for base directory build
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Assembling file list
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Expanding **/*
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Found 14 file(s)
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Preparing to copy secondary artifacts server
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Expanding base directory path: server
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Assembling file list
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Expanding server
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Expanding file paths for base directory server
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Assembling file list
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Expanding **/*
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:34:59 Found 12680 file(s)
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:35:02 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2022/04/12 00:35:02 Phase context status code:  Message:
```

The server artifacts are migrating correctly because the server sends responses, but it keeps returning a 404 error when I try to find the index.html file

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone's information in the future, I had the elastic beanstalk deploy stage in the pipeline only importing only the server artifacts, not all the artifacts lumped into a single folder. That's why it wasn't finding any of the build files, they weren't being imported as an artifact.